# Use dataframe column in functions

Tags: r, function, dataframe

When building function for column calculation, I simply define a function to code `y` according to `x` value,

But when I try to use a data frame column as `x` and `y`, it simply does not work whether I use `df$x`, `df[,x]` , or `df[[x]]` when i am using `code(col1, col2)`
what is the problem here?

```
code <- function(x,y)
{
y[x<=8]<-3
y[x>=9 & x<=11]<-1 
y[x>= 12 &x<=20]<-0
y[x>=21 &x<=24]<-2
y[x>=25]<-3}
```

Comment: Try using df[,"x"] or df[["x"]]

Comment: Please provide example data `df`, and expected output. Maybe try, `code(df$col1, df$col2)` ?

Comment: `code(df$col1, df$col2)` should work fine. You can also specify the data frame as an argument of the function `code <- function(x, y, df){...}`

Comment: Your function doesn't return the modified value of `y`. It should have `y` and just that as the last line of the function.

Answer (score 0):

i am simply using

z<-data.frame(x=sample(30),y=1)

if the "code" function working fine, if should calculate y according to x value.

when using

code(z&x,z$y),code(z[,"x"],z[,"y"]), code(z["x"],z["y"]) all does not work
,
and when add return(y),
it output this

[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[60] 3

but y in data frame z remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

actually can pass column as function input, but need to return the df in function, this works

```
    code<-function(x,y){
    y[x<=8]<-3
    y[x>=9 & x<=11]<-1
    y[x>= 12 &x<=20]<-0
    y[x>=21 &x<=24]<-2
    y[x>=25]<-3
    print(x)
    print(y)
    df<-data.frame(x,y)
    return(df)
    print(df)
     }
    z<- code(z$x,z$y)
```